# Check if Dataframe Values are Equal across specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

**CONTEXT**

I have two Dataframes and I want to validate that each DataFrame has the same value for each ID. I want to create a dataframe of all the rows/outliers that don't match.

The ID's are not in the same order and the dataframes do not have the same amount of rows.

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
DF1
ID    State    Occupation
111   AZ       Doctor
222   NY       Teacher
333   MO       Analyst
444   NC       Nurse

DF2
ID    State    Occupation
111   AZ       Doctor
222   NY       Teacher
333   MO       Analyst
444   NC       Student   <---- **It should flag this
```

The actual dataset is about 30,000+ rows.  Is it possible to do this based on the ID and assigning specific columns such as "State" and "Occupation" to check on for the two dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have the same number of rows and are sorted the same way according to the ID Column:

```
columns = ["State", "Occupation"]

df_error = df_1[((df_1 !=df_2)[columns]).any(1)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not in the same order and have different amount of rows. Thanks for pointing this out though, I've edited my question to reflect this!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question lacks specifics, so I assume the ID's are unique in each DataFrame :

```
check_cols = ["State", "Occupation"]

_df1 = df1.set_index("ID"); _df2 = df2.set_index("ID")

bool_diff = (_df1.ne(
    _df1.merge(_df2, left_index=True, right_index=True,
               suffixes=("_", ""))[check_cols]))

dict_diff = {i:{k:v for k,v in nd.items() if not pd.isna(v)} 
             for i,nd in _df2.where(
                 bool_diff).dropna(how="all").T.to_dict().items()}
```

Output :

```
print(bool_diff.all().all()) # False

print(dict_diff) # {444: {'Occupation': 'Student'}}
```

With the [*Styler*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html) :

```
(
    _df2.style.apply(
        lambda _: bool_diff.replace(
            {False: "", True: "background-color: lightcoral"}), axis=None)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming IDs can have different State or Occupation and you want to identify differences of both in either DF then you can merge the DFs to get rows with the same ID and then check the differences in columns of interest:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'ID': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555],
      'State': ['AZ', 'NY', 'MO', 'NC', 'NY'],
      'Occupation': ['Doctor', 'Teacher', 'Analyst', 'Doctor', 'Coder']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

d2 = {'ID': [111, 222, 333, 444],
      'State': ['AZ', 'NY', 'MO', 'NC'],
      'Occupation': ['Doctor', 'Teacher', 'Analyst', 'Student']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on = 'ID')

df_diff = df_merged[(df_merged['Occupation_x'].ne(df_merged['Occupation_y'])) \
                    | (df_merged['State_x'].ne(df_merged['State_y'])) ]
               
print(df_diff)
```

gives the required result:

```
    ID State_x Occupation_x State_y Occupation_y
3  444      NC       Doctor      NC      Student
```

having used the intermediary df_merged as below (note ID 555 is removed as not shared):

```
    ID State_x Occupation_x State_y Occupation_y
0  111      AZ       Doctor      AZ       Doctor
1  222      NY      Teacher      NY      Teacher
2  333      MO      Analyst      MO      Analyst
3  444      NC       Doctor      NC      Student
```